# navfn and carrot planner?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, carrot-planner, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to ROS and from past 5 days I'm trying create a launcher for navfn and carrot_planner. Can someone please help either by giving a step by step procedure or mail me the launcher if you have already written...

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36867/navfn-and-carrot-planner?/) by [nikhilsv92](https://answers.ros.org/users/2658/nikhilsv92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try looking at some example code in existing stacks:

1. [Erratic Robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Erratic)
2. [Turtlebot](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot)
3. [Guardian](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Guardian)

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0